# Adding Live Weather |Report to a webpage

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am working on development of a website. Task is to add a Live weather forecast to my webpage. I am unable to find a good working solution for this.

Comment: http://weather.weatherbug.com/desktop-weather/web-widgets.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consume [an RSS feed](http://www.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/) on current weather conditions from the National Weather Service.  (I'm assuming US, otherwise there may be a service local to your area as well.)  That information can be displayed on your site any way you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this on AccuWeather
http://netweather.accuweather.com

Answer (score 1):

I remember seeing something on [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASTGDWeatherControl.aspx) a while ago

> Through this article, I will create a
>   pretty ASP.NET weather control that
>   can be used in any ASP.NET page,
>   multiple times with different location
>   value.

There may be other examples [here](http://www.codeproject.com/info/search.aspx?artkw=weather).